# remove item from formBuilder

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angular-forms

When executing `formBuild.group` I am creating two values ​​that I use only for validations, these two values ​​do not want to save in the database, I would remove them before saving in the database.

**profile.component.ts:**

`profileForm: FormGroup;`

```
constructor(){
    this.profileForm = this.createPerfilForm();
 }

createProfileForm() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [this.perfil.id],
        name: [this.perfil.name, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(45)]],
        email: [this.perfil.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
        password: [''],
        passwordConfirm: ['', [confirmPassword]],
    });
}

saveProfile(){
     // I need to remove here password and passwordConfirm 
     //before saving to the database
     this.authService.updateProfile(this.profileForm.value);
}
```

I need to remove `this.profileForm.value` from the `password` and `passwordConfirm` values, since I do not want to save these values ​​in the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
saveProfile(){
     // I need to remove here password and passwordConfirm 
     //before saving to the database
     let copy = { ... this.profileForm.value };
     delete copy.password;
     delete copy.confirmPassword;
     this.authService.updateProfile(copy);
}
```

try this?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new object with only what you need:

```
 this.authService.updateProfile({id: this.profileForm.value.id, 
           name: this.profileForm.value.name, email:this.profileForm.value.email })
```